# Intel x86_64 asm : move pointer 4 by 4

Tags: assembly, nasm

i'm having fun with asm but there's something i don't understand, i was recoding the memset function, when i found out i had to increment my memory pointer pointer 4 by 4 in order to make it work. Why is it so ?

Thanks !

edit : Oh, and if you happen to have an explanation of the register's overlaying, i would be really grateful if you could share it ! I always move less than 64 bits arguments into [rax - eax - a*...] to split these. :-(

(my code :)

```
memset:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rax, rsi
    mov r11, rdi
loop:
    cmp rdx, 0
    jz end
    mov byte [rdi], al
    dec rdx
    add rdi, 4    <------ here the 4 increment
    jmp loop
end:
    mov rax, r11
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't look correct to me

Comment: I tried on several tests, and it only works with the 4. If i try memset(tab, 'z', 3) with "add rdi, 2", only the two first chars of the array will be changed. I don't understand it either, why an rdi pointing to 5040 could change the (char *)5010 ?

Comment: What happens with 1? What's the test? Doesn't this forget to write to 3 out of every 4 bytes?

Comment: you should look into [SOTSB, STOSW, STOSD](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-stosb.html)

Comment: My apologies, it works with 1... this is weird, i was sure it didn't work at first (i had spent 30 minute to change the second slot of the  array before doing the +4 !). Thanks very much for the guidance !